# Does the localStorage get cleared when working with npm live-server?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, npm-live-server, browser-close

I am currently working on a basic JS application that requires the usage of DOM storage or localStorage. In order to auto-save my changes, I incorporated the npm live-server.

After I shut down the live-server, I notice that the localStorage gets cleared. Can you help me understand how this happens under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is stored on the client side not on the server side, so each browser decides.
Read at MDN: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Thanks, Marten Steins